# How to add object to context handling duplicates correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4.4 and I have a One-To-Many relationship model like this:

```cs
class A { 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual B { get; set; }
   public int BId;
}
class B {
   public Id { get; set; }
   private ICollection<A> _As;
   public virtual ICollection<A> As
   {
      get { return _As ?? (_As = new HashSet<A>()); }
      protected set { _As = value; }
   }
}
```

Now, supposing I have 2 A instances, both with the same B instance. Then I'd have something like this (JSON representation):

```
A: { Id: 1, BId: 1, B: { Id: 1, As: [ 1, 2 ] } }
A: { Id: 2, BId: 1, B: { Id: 1, As: [ 1, 2 ] } }
```

I want to then cycle through my current list of A instances and add the to the db context:

```
foreach (var a in LocalAList)
{ 
   dbContext.Add(a);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that I get exceptions informing me that I've inserted duplicate objects. I've looked around and found things dealing with Entity modification and attachment, but I'm still pretty new to EF. I would imagine that this is a typical thing and there's an idiom for handling object insertion where the object already exists.

How can I efficiently add new objects to the context while avoiding the addition of duplicates? Should I just capture the duplicate exception and ignore it? Is there a better way to check?

Comment: Are the `Id`s database generated identities? And what exception do you get exactly? An exception about a primary key constraint violation? (In that case you can't have database generated identities, I think...) What do you want to insert exactly? Only the `A`s, or the `B`s as well? Or are the `B`s existing entities and you want only to create a relationship between new `A`s and existing `B`s?

Comment: See my edit. The Ids are NOT generated identities.

Comment: Honestly, I won't answer now anymore. For the sake of fairness to Mark Oreta's answer you should either roll back your edit to the former version and write a new question with your edit, or write a comment under Mark Oreta's answer that you have changed your question to give him a chance to adjust his answer. Your question change is so massive that his answer currently even doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: Agreed @Slauma; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255898/how-to-add-entities-to-dbcontext-with-recursive-relationships-while-avoiding-dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a simple test to see if a already exists in the database, the simplest one is to see if the Id is 0.  This is because once the A is added to the DB, an Id is given to your entity.  At that point, you should just reattach it rather than re-adding it

Example:

```
foreach (var a in LocalAList)
{ 
  if (a.Id == 0)
    dbContext.Add(a);
   else 
    dbContext.As.Attach(a)

   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```